# How To Ignore Null String Values Out Of A Series Of NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to parse data from the RSS Feed. From CDATA Block, i am also pulling the images by first catching the image urls. This is how i am using the CDATA method of nsxmlparser:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock {


    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [currentString appendString:someString];

    NSString *imageURLString = [self getFirstImageUrl:someString];
    NSLog(@"IMAGE URL STRING %@", imageURLString);

}
```

and this is the method i am that i have called from within above method:

```
-(NSString *)getFirstImageUrl: (NSString *) html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *imageURL = nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: html];

    // find start of tag
    [theScanner scanUpToString: @"<img" intoString: NULL];
    if ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString: @"src=\"" intoString: NULL];
        NSInteger newLoc2 = [theScanner scanLocation] + 5;
        [theScanner setScanLocation: newLoc2];

        // find end of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString: @"\"" intoString: &imageURL];
    }

    return imageURL;
}
```

As you can see, everything is clean and simply done. You can see the output below:

[image]

Is there any way it just don't receive the nulls and only take the image urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just *ignore* the nil valued strings yourself?

```
NSString *imageURLString = [self getFirstImageUrl:someString];
if (imageURLString)
    NSLog(@"IMAGE URL STRING %@", imageURLString);
```

Comment: Thanks. May be i was drunk not able to think that its that easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self getFirstImageUrl:someString];
```

shouldn't you be using your currentString variable?

also don't presume

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
```

will be called only once for a XML Node, you should create a new NSMutableData object when starting the node containing the CDATA, use the foundCDATA delegate method to appendData to your NSMutableData and only use your NSMutableData object when finishing to process the node (you have two delegate method for that)

Comment: even if you use currentString variable, the result would be the same. Can you provide some code how to handle the image urls from the nsmutabledata